# How to configure in cmake

Tags: dependencies, cmake

I am currently working on a project which is using cmake. The project has alsa as an optional dependency. Thus the projects `CMakeLists.txt` contains.

```
find_package(ALSA)
```

However I want the build to *never* build against alsa, even if if is on my system. (Kind of like the `--without-ALSA` that would have been in a `configure`)

I want to do this in a commandline-parameter when running cmake, not by modifying the  `CMakeLists.txt`

Is this possible with cmake?

EDIT:

**OR** would it be better to have the project implement something like this:

```
 if(WITH_ALSA)
    find_package(ALSA REQUIRED)
 elseif(NOT WITHOUT_ALSA)
    find_package(ALSA)
 endif()
```

EDIT2:

In the end I used the with & without option I described above (edit1). To have a little readability I defined a macro that acually does everything for me.
See the [FindOptionalPackage.cmake](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/blob/17411304b8046e782201d1e6fbc6865b664c2845/cmake/FindOptionalPackage.cmake) in the [FreeRDP project](http://freerdp.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run CMake and open the generated CMakeCache.txt file. You will find something like:

ALSA_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/alsa

(you basically just need to know how the variable is called). Then you should be able to call cmake with a parameter

```
-DALSA_INCLUDE_DIR=ALSA_INCLUDE_DIR_NOTFOUND
```

This tells cmake, that alsa is not on your system. If this does not work, try to look at other variables containing alsa and set them to some values indicating the library could not been found. If the FindALSA.cmake script is implemented correctly (i.e. does correct caching), this should work.

Comment: this (ALSA_INCLUDE_DIR_NOTFOUND) seems not to work. However, setting -DALSA_INCLUDE_DIR= (empty) works. BTW: This feels a bit like "tampering with variables" but I guess there is no intended way to do what I am aiming at in cmake?

Comment: @Nils: Yes - the problem is, that often you have to play around with several variables to figure out what you want to do. The cmake way would be that the developers would define a cached variable in the project like BUILD_WITH_ALSA which can be set to off

Comment: @Nils: In that code you will still search for ALSA, so it will still build with alsa as a dependency if CMake can find alsa. If you just remove the else case, it should work.

Comment: strange, I was under the impression that the above statement would work as follows: Use alsa as a required dependency if WITH_ALSA is given, do not use alsa at all if WITHOUT_ALSA is given and only use the "auto-discovery" if neither WITH_ALSA nor WITHOUT_ALSA is given. Maybe I need to dive into cmake a bit more…

Comment: @Nils: sorry, I did not read your code good enough - you are perfectly right!

Answer (score 0):

The above answer works, but doesnt really seem clean.

At work we do this (for example):

```
IF(WITH_FOO)
    FIND_PACKAGE(foo REQUIRED)
ENDIF()
```

or you could do:

```
IF(NOT WITHOUT_FOO)
    FIND_PACKAGE(foo REQUIRED)
ENDIF()
```

when you configure a cmake build, simply do

```
cmake -DWITH_FOO=1
```

or

```
cmake -DWITHOUT_FOO=1
```

Its clean, and it works guaranteed, and its easy to understand and read from the cmakefile.

Comment: Well, but I wanted to have exactly the three options: Use auto-discovery, depend (Required) or do not use... Your solution does not provide all three options.